# NSFileProviderExtension extension show download Progress

Tags: ios, swift, fileprovider-extension

I have implemented FileProvider Extension.

```
class MyProviderExtension: NSFileProviderExtension {

    override func startProvidingItem(at url: URL, completionHandler: ((_ error: Error?) -> Void)?) {
            downloading file using URL and implemented download delegates

// Download Delegate
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

**// How can I upload the download progress here.**
}

   }
}
```

I am not able to get any UI handler in download delegates to update the progress and update the cell download button after successful download.

Answer (score 1):

To support progress display on download/upload progress, you need to do:

1. Use NSURLSessionTask to download/upload files
2. Use NSURLSession with backgroundSession ([NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:])
3. Use [NSFileProviderManager registerURLSessionTask:forItemWithIdentifier:completionHandler:] to build task-identifier mapping.

Then the File Provider extension will show the progress on UI.

Comment: What we do if we have more than one NSURLSessionTask needed to be executed in order to complete the download?